# Adding shopping recommendations to the vote-to-close page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, on-off-topic, close-reasons, vote-to-close

There seems to be some consensus that shopping requests are often off-topic, particularly those that ask for recommendations for products rather than recommendations about what to look for in products:

- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/
- [Do we go shopping?](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276/do-we-go-shopping)
- [Product recommendation and comparison](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/826/product-recommendation-and-comparison)

A healthy portion of the questions which have currently received votes to close seem to fall under this category.

Unfortunately, the vote-to-close page only has one category in the "Closing > Off-topic" section: "General health and medical advice". Would it be possible to add a "shopping requests" category, too?

Comment: By the way, this wouldn't mean that all product-rec questions would be closed, but rather that it would be easier to vote on specific product-rec questions.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it would be possible. It requires the intervention of multiple moderators.

Got any suggestions on the exact text? We can include bold, links, etc.

Here's an example from another site:

> Questions seeking **product, service, or learning material recommendations** are off-topic because [they tend to become obsolete quickly](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I think that text is reasonable.